# Multiplexer output

Tags: computer-architecture, logic

The multiplexer is a device that selects one of several analog or digital input signals and forwards the selected input into a single line.

Please consider a, for example, [four data input multiplexer](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/DigitLogic/L77_0180_multiplexer.htm).

If I am not wrong, the last OR gate can produce as output only 1 and 0. How are these outputs interpreted as result of the input A, B, D or D?

Answer (score 1):

You are ignoring the control bits, which are also part of the input.

A 4-1 multiplexer also receives two control bits, $s_1s_2$ (sometimes called selection bits). Those bits determine what entry from the four inputs you want to select (pass forward as your output). Since you have four possible inputs, you need two control bits to specify which of one of $A,B,C,D$ you want to select.

Your single bit output is simply equal to the input bit determined by the control (say, if the control is $10$, then the output of the multiplexer is $C$). [Wikipedia's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer)  has better drawings and explanations.